# Vectical align text, while it should fill the div on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to force text to fill a div, while div height and width and unknown. The text size should be flexible, depending on parent. I want to archieve something like this:

[image]

The page is mobile only, so I need to support all android/iphone browsers. The main problem is that each mobile browser support different things and it's hard to get such thing working on most* devices.

I tried setting `meta viewport width="640"` - it's working well on the newest major browser but all lower browser have their own realisation and it's breaking.

The next thing which came to my mind is using viewport units, but their support is bad too (http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)

I came up with the following code for the font-size:

```
var ratio = parent.offsetWidth * 85/100 / text.offsetWidth - 0.3;

text.style.fontSize = (10 * ratio > 85 ? 85 : 10 * ratio) + "px";
```

but still it's not that precise and vectical centering is still a mistery.

Comment: You can't support "all". "All" doesn't exist, it's impossible to use correctly in the real world.

Comment: I meant most popular devices. Atleast android 4.0+ browsers.

Comment: I wonder why the parent div's height is unknown, if it has only one `REGISTER` textNode child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe setting font-size dynamically is the right way to achieve this. But rather than `width`, you can consider using `height` as ratio. So calculating `div`'s height is probably ineluctable.

For vertical alignment, there are several solutions:

1. Wrap text in a span. And set the span's `display` to `inline-block`. Add to the span a pseudo element of which the `height` is 100%. Set `vertical-align: middle`to both span and pseudo element, as described [here](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/). Make sure that you set the parent `div`'s height, using Javascript if necessary.
2. Set the `line-height` to the same as the `div`'s height.
3. Set both parent div and children span's `height`, and `display: block; margin: auto`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to marked it as answered. The 2nd suggestion did the work, thanks!